# Moving a mysql database from one vps to another

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm moving a large wordpress mysql db (1.49gb) from an old server to a new one, what I did was to:

```
mysqldump -u root -p dbname > public_location/db.sql
```

then I did a:

```
wget http://oldserver/db.sql
```

I created the database on the new server, created the user, then:

```
mysqldump -u root -p dbname < db.sql
```

It says dump completed, but why is the database on the new server still empty? I don't see any tables at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than call `mysqldump` on the new server with the input file, just call `mysql`

```
mysql -u root -p dbname < db.sql
```

You can, if you are brave and the second VPS has port 3306 open to the old one via TCP and you have a user account `root@oldserver` able to do the write, do this in one action:

```
# Pipe the dump directly from the old vps to the new vps:
mysqldump -uroot -p dbname | mysql -h newserver -uroot -p dbname
```

I wouldn't attempt it over the Internet, but I've done it on a LAN several times.

Finally, don't forget the `--routines` parameter if you have stored functions and procedures that need to migrate with the database. They won't go into the dump without it.

```
mysqldump --routines -u root -p dbname > public_location/db.sql
```

Comment: Ah, it's always with the simple ones i tend to fail. Thanks!

Comment: Also add the -c flag for complete inserts - it makes the dump file more viable over long periods of time if you change your schema.